# ADO.net Performing Multiple queries (ExecuteQuery & ExecuteScalar) and displaying the result in a web form control

Tags: sql, asp.net, ado.net

Hey wish you all to have a happy holiday,

I am trying to display multiple query results from a SQL database table to a grid view control and a label. I have no problem with the grid view result, but the result from the ExecuteScalar command is not displaying inside my lable control with an ID="myCount". I could not figure out what went wrong with my code. I need your help.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MBSDB"].ConnectionString);
        try {
            conn.Open();
            string query="SELECT * FROM tblBook";
            using (SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)) {
                myGrid.DataSource = mycmd.ExecuteReader();
                myGrid.DataBind();
            }



            string query2 = "SELECT count(title) FROM tblBook";
            using (SqlCommand mycmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, conn)) {
                int count = (int)mycmd2.ExecuteScalar();
                myCount.Text = count.ToString();

            }


        }
        catch { 
        Exception(e);
        }
        finally { conn.Close(); }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a exception or does it simply not display the value?

Comment: No there are no exceptions displaying, only the grid view results from the ExecuteReader command are displaying, but the ExecuteScalar command is not returning anything.

Comment: Can you show the where is myCount defined/set?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about there is no error. I think, the error occured and handling in the catch block and you are unaware of it.

You should change it;

```
(int)mycmd2.ExecuteScalar();
```

to

```
Convert.ToInt32(mycmd2.ExecuteScalar());
```

You can't unboxing an object like this; `(int)mycmd2.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: I tried to parse the object just as you directed me, but it still doesn't show the result. May be it's the form control i.e the <asp:Lable><Lable/> that i used. Should I be using another form control? Do you have any suggestions?